# How to deploy a camel java DSL servlet on Tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-camel, maven-jetty-plugin

I have found several examples of camel servlet for tomcat server using spring DSL, I want to use Java DSL and create a RouteBuilder as shown below. This servlet works as expected on Jetty when I run using mvn jetty:run command, but doesn't work with tomcat server.

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class DefaultRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("DefaultRouter");
        from("servlet:hello?matchOnUriPrefix=true").process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String contentType = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, String.class);
                String path = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, String.class);
                path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"));
                exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType + "; charset=UTF-8");
                exchange.getOut().setHeader("PATH", path);
                exchange.getOut().setBody("<b>Hello World</b>");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As per my understanding my web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<webapp>
  <display-name>camel-servlet</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>name</param-name>
        <param-value>MyCamel</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>routeBuilder-MyRoute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.camel.community.so.servletlistener.DefaultRouteBuilder</param-value>
    </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.camel.component.servletlistener.JndiCamelServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/camel/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</webapp>
```

Edit:
Logs from mvn jetty:run command -

```
[INFO] Scanning elapsed time=1409ms
[INFO] DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
[INFO] No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
[INFO] node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2022-07-19 11:15:39,454 [main           ] INFO  CamelServletContextListener    - CamelContextServletListener initializing ...
DefaultRouter
2022-07-19 11:15:39,797 [main           ] INFO  ServletCamelContext            - Apache Camel 2.25.0 (CamelContext: MyCamel) is starting
2022-07-19 11:15:39,804 [main           ] INFO  ManagedManagementStrategy      - JMX is enabled
2022-07-19 11:15:40,094 [main           ] INFO  DefaultTypeConverter           - Type converters loaded (core: 195, classpath: 9)
2022-07-19 11:15:40,233 [main           ] INFO  ServletCamelContext            - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2022-07-19 11:15:40,272 [main           ] INFO  ServletCamelContext            - Route: route1 started and consuming from: servlet:/hello?matchOnUriPrefix=true
2022-07-19 11:15:40,274 [main           ] INFO  ServletCamelContext            - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2022-07-19 11:15:40,276 [main           ] INFO  ServletCamelContext            - Apache Camel 2.25.0 (CamelContext: MyCamel) started in 0.483 seconds
2022-07-19 11:15:40,277 [main           ] INFO  CamelServletContextListener    - CamelContextServletListener initialized
2022-07-19 11:15:40,316 [main           ] INFO  CamelHttpTransportServlet      - Initialized CamelHttpTransportServlet[name=CamelServlet, contextPath=/camel-example-servlet]
[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2764c546{Camel Servlet Example,/camel-example-servlet,file:///C:/Users/rrdoshi/Downloads/camel-example-servlet/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Users/rrdoshi/Downloads/camel-example-servlet/src/main/webapp/}
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@2b73bd6b{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started @8097ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

For tomcat deployment, I am placing the war file in tomcat webapps directory and executing startup.bat

```
19-Jul-2022 11:21:21.403 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
19-Jul-2022 11:21:21.576 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [146] milliseconds.
19-Jul-2022 11:21:21.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\ApacheCamelDemoServlet]
19-Jul-2022 11:21:21.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\ApacheCamelDemoServlet] has finished in [49] ms
19-Jul-2022 11:21:21.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\docs]
19-Jul-2022 11:21:21.671 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\docs] has finished in [25] ms
19-Jul-2022 11:21:21.672 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\examples]
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\examples] has finished in [425] ms
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.099 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\host-manager]
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.135 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [36] ms
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.136 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\manager]
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.175 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\manager] has finished in [38] ms
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.175 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\ROOT]
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.202 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\rrdoshi\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [26] ms
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.205 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.224 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [2721] milliseconds
```

access logs

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2022:11:23:51 +0530] "GET /camel-servlet/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1675
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2022:11:24:01 +0530] "GET /camel-servlet/camel/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 784
```

localhost logs

```
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
19-Jul-2022 11:21:22.087 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@68ab0936')
```

The WAR file is getting deployed but there are no error logs. There are no logs regarding camelContext starting up.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work on Tomcat? Please provide specific information on what is failing, potentially with relevant logs. Do you see your war getting deployed when tomcat starts up? Do you see camel context starting up?

Comment: @ShellDragon I have added edits, did I miss anything out?